# First on Enum throw "sequence contains no elements"

Tags: c#, dynamic, ienumerable

I have the subsequent code :

```
if ( myList.Where ( .. condition .. ).Where ( .. another condition .. ).Any() )
{
     var element = myList.Where ( .. condition .. ).Where ( .. another condition .. ).First().Elements ;

     ..some logic over element ..
}
```

I get the exception "Sequence contains no elements" on the first line inside the IF statement.

myList is a `List<MyObject>` where MyObject inherits form ExpandoObject and has a getter called Elements, that return to me the object casted as dynamic.

Edit as requested i try to get more detail over the query executed in both any and first.

```
myList.Where ( x => x.Child.Name.Equal ( "Name" ).Where ( x => x.Elements.Value == myValue )
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - aside from anything else, we don't know if the conditions are the same between the two lines, and whether the data source is stable. (In general, I'd advise avoiding this sort of double-evaluation...)

Comment: Well, what explanation are you looking for? There's no item that satisfies your filters. And why are you doing `Any`+`First` instead of just doing `FirstOrDefault` in the first place?

Comment: A side note. Why do you write `sequence.Where(condition).Any()` instead of `sequence.Any(condition)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet the queries are the same

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean the *results* will be the same...

Comment: @Luaan you are right, but i need to mantain that code and actually it use Any + First instead of FirstOrDefault (a lot of times).
I would like to understand the why of my problem (occur very rarely) before rewrite all the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that nothing matches your `where` condition(s) before the call to `First()`. Given that you aren't showing actual code, it's difficult to tell whether the conditions are the same but the best approach would be to re-write it like this:

```
var thing = myList.Where ( .. condition .. ).Where ( .. another condition .. ).FirstOrDefault();

if (thing != null)
{
    var element = thing.Element;
    ..some logic over element ..
}
```

This has the benefit of not duplicating the `where` condition(s) twice and saves the double enumeration of the input source which depending on what `myList` actually is could suffer performance penalties.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var myValue = myList.Where(..condition..).Where(..another condition..).FirstOrDefault();
if ( myValue != null )
{
     var element = myValue.Elements ;
     ..some logic over element ..
}
```

You use the fact that if there are no results you get a null, and check against the null rather than perform the query twice. Also, if you need to change the query you only have one place to change it.

I imagine that your error was caused by the preceding predicates being slightly different in the `.Any()` and the `.First()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `FirstOrDefault()`!

```
var element= myList.FirstOrDefault(x => condition1 && condition2 && ...);

if(element!= null)
{
    // Apply logic over the element
}
```